# finite covering: is this statement correct?

Tags: analysis

I'm learning about Finite Covering Theorem, there is a statement on the textbook that "Finite Covering Theorem does not mean that any close interval can be covered by a finite number of open intervals".

I'm a bit confused here, for a close interval [a,b], I can always have (a-1, b+1) $\supset$ [a,b], doesn't it mean that all the close intervals can.be covered by a single open interval? Is there any counter example for this?

Thanks for answering this
........................................................
Update: I put the original content here:

So heres the paragraph(the book is written.in Chinese so what I post here is a translated version):

" About the Finite Covering Theorem, there are two points to note:

1. the interval being covered must be a closed interval;

2.The theorem only states that for a closed interval, if you have a open covering of it, you can always take a finite number of open intervals out of that open covering which together cover the closed interval. not that any closed interval can be covered by a finite number of open intervals. if so, (a-1, b+1) is always a finite open covering of [a,b].

There are no any further assumptions about the boundedness of these intervals

Comment: Are they assuming all open intervals are bounded?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us the statement of that theorem from the book, and some context for the line that puzzles you - perhaps the paragraph it's in. Then perhaps we can help.

Comment: Finite covering theorem is valid for closed and bounded sets. You can take an unbounded closed set for your counter example.

Comment: Assuming that we're talking about $\mathbb R$, consider the closed set $[1,\infty)$, now clearly for this set not every open covering has finite subcover.

Comment: Hi, i just posted the paragraph in the edited question. to be honest the statement sounds a bit weird even in Chinese. I just realize that pehaps I misunderstand the statement, doesn't the author say so simply to highlight that the content of the Finite Covering Theorem is not about the simple fact that“any closed interval have finte open covering”but about “any open covering of a closed interval includes a finite open covering of it”.   It looks somehow like a problem of my misunderstanding of the author's wording

Comment: This may be a language problem, but the theorem does not apply to any closed interval, but to closed and *bounded* intervals. In particular. for any real number $a$, $[a, \infty), (-\infty, a]$, and $(-\infty, \infty)$ are all closed intervals, because they contain their boundary points ($a$ for the first two, and the third has no boundary points, so it automatically contains all of them). Yet they are easy to cover with open intervals so that there is no finite sub cover: consider the collection of sets $\{(n,n+2)\mid n \in \Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: Ok I think Ive got the point, thank you